# Section formula ratio assumption and confusion

Tags: geometry

> What is the equation of the line which passes through $(-4,3)$ and the portion of the line intercepted between the axis is divided internally in the ratio $5:3$ by this point?

This is easy but I am confused which part of the portion must be assumed $5$ and which one $3$.

Comment: My guess is that the "left-hand" side is 5 parts, and the "right-hand" side is 3 parts. That is, when you draw the line in the normal coordinate system (where $x$ is growing to the right) ... I would recommend that you sketch the coordinate system and the line, and then continue with the problem.

Comment: The "Repo" thing is for ethical standards of the site.

Comment: You can consider both options, finding two different solutions.